# beforeunload on IE 11 - do not prompt user does not work

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, onbeforeunload

When adding a listener to the global window object for the `beforeunload` event, IE 11 (and 10) does not behave as Chrome and Firefox.

Normally, you return a string that will be used to populate the browser-native dialog prompt or you return an empty string if you do not want the dialog to prompt the user.

However, in IE 11, if you return an empty string and/or set the `evt.returnValue` to an empty string, the browser-native 'Navigate Away' dialog is opened and prompts the user to acknowledge that they may lose unsaved changes.

Is there any way (without having to remove the event listener) to have the dialog not appear in IE 11?

See my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dpark/wx59x1ht/29/) (in IE - as this should work properly in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari).

Here's the source in the fiddle:

```javascript
var isDirty = false;
var message = '** You have unsaved changes. **'
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(evt){
  if(isDirty) {
    evt.returnValue = message;
    return message;
  }
  delete  evt.returnValue;
  return "";
});
```

Comment: I doubt IE needs a real `false` instead of `""`. Also, `returnValue` doesn't exist in the modern event handling model.

Comment: I'm not returning `false` anywhere.  Thanks for tip on `returnValue`.  I am aware of it's absence in modern event handling.  The logic around `returnValue` is for good measure.

Comment: My comment was maybe a bit unclear. I meant, that you should return `false` instead of  `""'`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The solution is not to return anything (which is the same as `return;` or `return undefined;`).

```
var isDirty = false;
var message = '** You have unsaved changes. **'
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(evt){
  if(isDirty) {
    evt.returnValue = message;
    return message;
  }
  delete evt.returnValue;
});
```

Comment: This is correct! You should mark as solved, just spent an hour trying to figure this out.